# Convert EPS/PDF to JPEG/PNG?

Tags: .net, pdf, eps

I need to be able to take EPS and PDF's and convert them to JPEG/PNG on the fly to display on a website - using .net code.

I used [ADC PDF from WebSupergoo](http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd) for this like 3 years ago, and it worked fine - but some other and better options could easily have surfaced since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php); you could call the command line tool from your code to do conversion. They also have a .Net wrapper called MagickNet http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx

Comment: ImageMagick + Ghostscript is a nightmare to install and make work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple conversion you can use ghostview... for example:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=png16m -r300x300 -sOutputFile=junk.png -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE Figure_001-a.pdf
```

Converts the PDF at a 300x300 DPI to a png.

Answer (score 0):

Foxit Reader is a really good PDF reader.  They have an SDK you can use.  For more imaging operations try something like this toolkit www.atalasoft.com.  they also have a great web viewer.  see their domo at http://www.atalasoft.com/ajaxannotations/default.aspx